# android ListView item click

Tags: android

Hello friends I have problem in item click listener on `ListView` in android... My code tells me right position of item but not right name I need help... Im new in android...

Here is my code

```
public void listView(){

            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_View);
            final String[][] projections = {{Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_CALORIE, Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_FAT}};
            final String selection = Food.NewDishInfo.DISH_NAME+" LIKE ?";
            String[] selection_args = new String[]{"dish_name"};
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_layout,selection_args);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    String selection_args = "You selected " +
                            String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

                    Toast.makeText(DataListActivity.this,"position : " + i +selection_args, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
```

This is my list adapter code.....

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {

        super(context, resource);
    }
    static class LayoutHandler{
        TextView name,calorie,fat;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_name);
            layoutHandler.calorie = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_calorie);
            layoutHandler.fat = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_fat);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.name.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.calorie.setText(dataProvider.getCalorie());
        layoutHandler.fat.setText(dataProvider.getFat());


        return row;
    }
}
```

datalistactivity code...

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DataListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    FoodDbHelper foodDbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);
        listView();

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_View);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = foodDbHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String name,calorie,fat;
                name = cursor.getString(0);
                calorie = cursor.getString(1);
                fat = cursor.getString(2);
                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name,calorie,fat);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    public void listView(){

        List list = new ArrayList();
        ArrayListt ArrayListt = null;


        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_View);
        final String ArrayListtt = new String((char[]) null);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_layout, Integer.parseInt(ArrayListtt));
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        String ArrayListtt = "You selected " +
                                String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

                        Toast.makeText(DataListActivity.this, "position : " + i + ArrayListtt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }



                });
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "dish name is : " + dataprovider.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ok do the following 
**Step 1:**
Create hashmap (Which is outside of adapter)

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> selectedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

**Step 2:**

When the checkBox clicked add your value in HAshMap (key is your position and values are calories)
example:

```
layoutHandler.names.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
selectedItems.put(position, your_calory_values);
}});
```

**Step 3:**

When user click the sum button do it

```
sum_button.setOnclickL....
{
float sum = 0.0f;
            for (float f : selectedItems.values()) {
                sum += f;
            }
            Log.e("x", sum+"**");
 Toast.makeText(DataListActivity.this, sum+"**", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

**Edit:**

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int listPos = listView.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        DataProvider item = (DataProvider) listDataAdapter.getItem(listPos);
        Log.i("", "");
        CheckBox names = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

       selectedItems.put(listPos, Integer.valueOf(dataProvider.getCalorie()));     
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) buttonView;
        final DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) checkBox.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Click on : " + dataProvider.getName()+ checkBox.getText() +
                        " " + checkBox.isChecked(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dataProvider.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());
```

Comment: hello brother how how can i add velue in hashmap     dataProvider.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());   this line add my all check in dataprovider and then i can access it by button ...but how can i add value in hashmap

Comment: Declare this line final HashMap<Integer, Integer> selectedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); inside of Activity class and no need for final. Following is enough
 HashMap<Integer, Integer> selectedItems = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

Comment: yes i try this code but when i click on check app carash

Comment: Crashes happening every time don't afraid of it. What is the issue. tell me the crash i will help you.

Comment: You are adding question in answer avoid negative vote please remove it.

Comment: brother will jo help me on skype or tream viewer ?

Comment: ok brother leave sum.......when i check select and scroll down my app crash what is the problem?

Comment: Post logcat. then only i can check your issue.

Comment: Join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/79406/help-here?tab=general

Comment: i have  8 reputation not enough for upload picture and chat

Comment: give me your facebook id i will send u picture of logcat