# Checkbox not working properly on listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I made a listview from db and I added onitemclicklistener. When I click on the item it will take me to the next activity and show full detail of the item. I also added a checkbox on the listview which checks the item. The problem is that when I click on the checkbox it wont work, but when I click on the item, it starts the next activity and after it, when I go back to the listview and try again to click on the checkbox, then this item checkbox works and the other one doesn't work. Also  when I select a second item from the listview and go back then the checkbox works. Checkbox only works on that item with at least one time click. Does someone have an idea of what could be causing this problem? Here's my Java:

```
public class DataListActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    FoodDbHelper foodDbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;

    ListDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    Button button;
    DataProvider dataProvider;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);





        checkButtonClick();






        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_View);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        foodDbHelper = new FoodDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = foodDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = foodDbHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String name,quantity,calorie,fat,protein,sugar,vitamins;
                boolean selected = false;
                String names = null;

                name = cursor.getString(0);
                quantity = cursor.getString(1);
                calorie = cursor.getString(2);
                fat = cursor.getString(3);
                protein = cursor.getString(4);
                sugar = cursor.getString(5);
                vitamins = cursor.getString(6);

                DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name,quantity,calorie,fat,protein,sugar,vitamins,names,selected);

                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position, long id) {

                String name = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_name)).getText();
                String quantity = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_quantity)).getText();
                String calorie = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_calorie)).getText();
                String fat = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_fat)).getText();
                String protein = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_protein)).getText();
                String sugar = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_sugar)).getText();
                String vitamins = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_vitamins)).getText();

                String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "dish name is : " + name,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      CheckBox names = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                   names.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {

                           CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;

                           DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) checkBox.getTag();
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                   "Clicked on Checkbox: " + dataProvider.getName() + checkBox.getText() +
                                           " is " + checkBox.isChecked(),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           dataProvider.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());

                       }
                   });





                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Detail.class);
                intent.putExtra("Dish name",name);
                intent.putExtra("Dish quantity",quantity);
                intent.putExtra("Dish calorie",calorie);
                intent.putExtra("Dish fat",fat);
                intent.putExtra("Dish protein",protein);
                intent.putExtra("Dish sugar",sugar);

                intent.putExtra("Dish vitamins",vitamins);

                startActivity(intent);

            }


        });}

        private void checkButtonClick() {

            List list = new ArrayList();

            listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.row_layout,list);





            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                    responseText.append("The following dishes were selected...\n");




                    ArrayList<DataProvider> list = (ArrayList<DataProvider>) listDataAdapter.list;
                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                        DataProvider dataProvider = list.get(i);


                        if (dataProvider.isSelected()) {
                            responseText.append("\n" + dataProvider.getName()+" : " + dataProvider.getCalorie()+" kcal");
                        }


                    }


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });


}



}
    public class DataProvider {
    private String name = null;
    private String quantity;
    private String calorie;
    private String fat;
    private String protein;
    private String sugar;
    private String vitamins;
    private String names = null;
    boolean selected = false;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity){
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getCalorie(){
        return calorie;
    }
    public void setCalorie(String calorie){
        this.calorie = calorie;
    }
    public String getFat(){
        return fat;
    }
    public void setFat(String fat){
        this.fat = fat;
    }
    public String getProtein(){
        return protein;
    }
    public void setProtein(String protein){
        this.protein = protein;
    }
    public String getSugar() {return sugar; }
    public void setSugar(String sugar) {this.sugar = sugar ;}
    public String getVitamins() {return vitamins; }
    public void setVitamins(String vitamins) {this.vitamins = vitamins ;}

    public String getNames() {return names; }
    public void setNames(String names) {this.names = names ;}
    public boolean isSelected()
    {return selected;}
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {this.selected = selected;}


    public DataProvider(String name,String quantity,String calorie, String fat,String protein,String sugar,String vitamins,String names, boolean selected){
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.calorie = calorie;
        this.fat = fat;
        this.protein = protein;
        this.sugar = sugar;
        this.vitamins = vitamins;
        this.names = names;
        this.selected = selected;

    }

    public void add(List list) {

    }
}



    public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {


    List list = new ArrayList();


    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {


        super(context, resource);
    }

    public ListDataAdapter(DataListActivity dataListActivity, int row_layout, List list) {

        super(dataListActivity, row_layout, list);
    }


    static class LayoutHandler{
        TextView name,quantity,calorie,fat,protein,sugar,vitamins;
        CheckBox names;

    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {

        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();


    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);


    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_name);
            layoutHandler.quantity = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_quantity);
            layoutHandler.calorie = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_calorie);
            layoutHandler.fat = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_fat);
            layoutHandler.protein = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_protein);
            layoutHandler.sugar = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_sugar);
            layoutHandler.vitamins = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_dish_vitamins);
            layoutHandler.names = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            row.setTag(layoutHandler);


        }
        else
        {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.name.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.quantity.setText(dataProvider.getQuantity());
        layoutHandler.calorie.setText(dataProvider.getCalorie());
        layoutHandler.fat.setText(dataProvider.getFat());
        layoutHandler.protein.setText(dataProvider.getProtein());
        layoutHandler.sugar.setText(dataProvider.getSugar());
        layoutHandler.vitamins.setText(dataProvider.getVitamins());

        layoutHandler.names.setChecked(dataProvider.isSelected());
        layoutHandler.names.setTag(dataProvider);



        return row;
    }




}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should write the onclick on checkbox instead of writing on list items.

Comment: Check my answer for [Single selection in RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview/29030776#29030776)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some of the things:

**Step 1:**

Need to modify getView..

Here only you need to add the action for checkbox

example :

```
layoutHandler.names.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {

                           CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;

                           DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) checkBox.getTag();
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                   "Clicked on Checkbox: " + dataProvider.getName() + checkBox.getText() +
                                           " is " + checkBox.isChecked(),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           dataProvider.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());

                       }
                   });
```

**Step 2:**

Once you are add checkBox in a listView row then click action causing issues.
You can solve this that is you need to trigger itemclick action from getView method

example:

```
//I am adding an extra widget 
layoutHandler.layout = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
```

then click action

```
layoutHandler.layout.setOnclick.....
```

Under this trigger item click action using `performItemClick`

```
layoutHandler.layout.performItemClick(...
```

Comment: now i want to sum of  my calories item which i selected by checkbox and show me the  tolall calories of item which i selected .....on clicking button show toast your calories is totall .........total calories.....here is my code          <>

Comment: I am not able to see the code. What is the issue? can you edit your question

Comment: You better do one thing post that as an additional question in stackOverflow. This is confusing.

Comment: brother i can not post new question before 4 day because there is some problem here....plzzz help me in .......add an other answer

Comment: I added answer in your another question of yours. Which is similar to this. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426316/android-listview-item-click/30589992#30589992 Ask any doubts

Comment: Ask me if you have any doubts.

Comment: plz check there i try but not complete it plz see my code of DataListActivity at the end where checkbox are there